# QT Visual studio trying to compile project on a different PC

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5

I am trying to open a qt project on my personal pc but so far without success,when i try to build there is some files that are always missing.

QT Version: 5.6
Visual studio version: 2015

[image]

After searching the web cant find/figure out what i should do, i am little experienced with qt.

What should i do ? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your `.pro` file?And you need to do `qmake` or something equally.

Comment: Does the project contain a *.pro file? If so, you should open the project in Qt Creator, not Visual Studio. If the project doesn't contain a *.pro file, please edit your question to provide details on how you opened the project.